# How to draw map for specific country in r plot from a whole world raster and that specific country’s shapefile?

Tags: r, spatial

I have raster data for whole world (filename.bil) and a Shapefile (filename.shp) for USA. How to draw map for USA by using the raster data (filename.bil) in R plot?

```
shape <- shapefile(file.path(gadmdir,"gadm36_USA_1.shp”))
b <- brick(file.path(gaezdir, "plate47.bil"))
r <- raster(shape, res=0.0833333 )
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
cropextent <- mask(r, shape)

plot(cropextent)
```

Comment: Please post enough code and data to make this reproducible.

Comment: I have posted the code. Thank you.

Comment: Still need some data to work with. Some guidance here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that makes raster and shape data and extracts the raster values from the extent of the shape. It's a modification of the help text for the `raster::crop` function.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
r <- raster(nrow=450, ncol=900)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

# crop Raster* with Spatial* object
b <- as(extent(0, 10, 40, 50), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(b) <- crs(r)
rb <- crop(r, b)

plot(r)
plot(b, add=T)
```

[image]

```
plot(rb)
```

[image]

Comment: This won’t work in my case. Because it won’t give the shape of the country. This command will just crop the raster in rectangular form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crop` followed by `mask`

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
p <- getData("GADM", country="Mexico", level=1)
```

Solution

```
x <- crop(r, p)
y <- mask(x, p)
```

Have a look

```
#original 
plot(r)
lines(p)

# processed
plot(y)
lines(p)
```